# meaning of doublerule

Tags: latex, tex

what's the meaning of the term doublerule in the publishing industry? anyone can provide an example please.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule is a line. So a double rule would be a double line, like under a chapter heading in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, helped a lot :)